# Problems with speed testing (HDD Caching in Windows?)

Tags: c#, windows, performance, performance-testing

I am working on a tool to analyse large raw data files (coming from a mass-spectrometer but that is irrelevant to my problem). Such files are about 4 to 8GB large binary files. In order to access these files I have two APIs from the instruments vendor at my disposal.

My current task is to figure out which one of the two APIs is faster. The problem now is that, every time I run the same raw file in my tool more then once, the second time is much much faster (we are talking about a change from 10 to 2 minutes) even if I close and restart the application each time (there is no caching happening from my side and as far as I know also not from the API)
This of course makes it very difficult to perform proper performance benchmarks.

Is there a known mechanism in Windows (7 to 10) that does same large scale file caching? Do hard-drives have such a large cache? Is there any way how I can disable it so that I can run the same file in subsequent tests so that it will always perform like the first time?

Thanks for your help
Oli

Comment: For a single time testing (evaluating APIs) you can bluntly reboot PC before running either test. This will ensure in same initial conditions. Other idea is to measure *warmed-up* performance. If file access speed is constant, then difference in that will reveal better API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer hides in details behind your words

> ...access these files...

The effect that caching has on corresponding performance is totally determined by the way in which the files are accessed. Such a huge difference between the first and further runs that you observe i.e. 10 vs 2 mins clearly shows that the access is not straightforward.

Try writing or reading a 4GB file sequentially and through. You will never hit a cache and no cache would ever help you.

What would I suggest? Start here:

[File caching in Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364218(v=vs.85).aspx)

[Limit the file caching](https://superuser.com/questions/422113/how-could-i-limit-or-even-disable-file-cache-on-windows-server-2008r2)

But do not cherish your hope to get away with that. File access became so darn complicated and layered these days, just like onions...or ogres.

What else would I suggest? Quit fighting the file system optimizations. Live with that. Make your testing "above" the file system i.e. compare the APIs on "cold" cache and separately compare them on "hot" cache. This seems more close to the real world.